# BeautifulSoup nested tags

Tags: python, xml, nested, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse an XML with Beautifulsoup, but hit a brick wall when trying to use the "[recursive](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#arg-recursive)" attribute with findall()

I have a pretty odd xml format shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
      <book>true</book>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
      <book>false</book>
   </book>
 </catalog>
```

As you can see, the book tag repeats inside the book tag, which causes an error when I try to to something like:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup as BSS

catalog = "catalog.xml"


def open_rss():
    f = open(catalog, 'r')
    return f.read()

def rss_parser():
    rss_contents = open_rss()
    soup = BSS(rss_contents)
    items = soup.findAll('book', recursive=False)

    for item in items:
        print item.title.string

rss_parser()
```

As you will see, on my soup.findAll I've added recursive=false, which in theory would make it no recurse through the item found, but skip to the next one.

This doesn't seem to work, as I always get the following error:

```
  File "catalog.py", line 17, in rss_parser
    print item.title.string
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here, and would appreciate if someone could give me some help on how to solve this problem.

Changing the HTML structure is not an option, this this code needs to perform well as it will potentially parse a large XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`soup.findAll('catalog', recursive=False)` will return a list containing only your top-level "catalog" tag. Since that doesn't have a "title" child, `item.title` is `None`.

Try `soup.findAll("book")` or `soup.find("catalog").findChildren()` instead.

**Edit:** OK, the problem wasn't what I thought it was. Try this:

```
BSS.NESTABLE_TAGS["book"] = []
soup = BSS(open("catalog.xml"))
soup.catalog.findChildren(recursive=False)
```

Comment: .children errors, and doing it by "book" only returns the first item

Comment: My mistake, I've corrected it to findChildren(). But `.findAll("book")` works for me. Are you sure you used findAll, not find?

Comment: My bad, *I* ended up posting the wrong XML here. I've slightly updated the structure of it so it represents exactly what I have, and the reason why soup.findAll("book" doesn't work for me

Comment: @Marcos: OK, I see what you've done. I've added some more code in the solution.

Comment: @Thomas I'd be cautious about overriding the attributes like that. Subclassing is much safer.

Comment: @marcog: If you're writing a serious program, yes. But the combination of BeautifulSoup and broken XML makes it look like this is a quick and dirty cleanup job.

Answer (score 4):

It appears the problem lies in the nested `book` tags. BautifulSoup has a predefined set of tags that can be nested (`BeautifulSoup.NESTABLE_TAGS`), but it doesn't know that `book` can be nested, so it goes wonkers.

[Customizing the parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Customizing%20the%20Parser),  explains what's going on and how you can subclass `BeautifulStoneSoup` to customise the nestable tags. Here's how we can use it to fix your problem:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

class BookSoup(BeautifulStoneSoup):
  NESTABLE_TAGS = {
      'book': ['book']
  }

soup = BookSoup(xml) # xml string omitted to keep this short
for book in soup.find('catalog').findAll('book', recursive=False):
  print book.title.string
```

If we run this, we get the following output:

```
XML Developer's Guide
Midnight Rain
```

Comment: Any examples you could give me? Can't seem to get it to work!

Answer (score -1):

Beautifulsoup is slow and dead, use lxml instead:)

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> rss = open('/tmp/catalog.xml')
>>> items = etree.parse(rss).xpath('//book/title/text()')
>>> items
["XML Developer's Guide", 'Midnight Rain']
>>>
```

Comment: 3.2.0 was released 6 weeks ago. How is that dead?

Comment: @marcog: Sort of. There was a 3.1 series and a 3.0 series. Development stalled with 3.1. 3.1 had serious bugs, but people kept using it because it *appeared* to be the latest release. So the author basically re-released the latest in the 3.0 branch as 3.2. You can read more here: http://www.crummy.com/2010/11/21/0

Comment: Anyway, these are different tools. BeautifullSoup is greating for reading broken XML as in "wild" html. In this case, it looks like etree could be used without any problem.

Comment: lxml could handle broken xml too